# Problem with definition in C++ under VS2010

Tags: c++

Been working on some code and thought it would be a bit clever to try and implement some fast workaround define functions. Yet everything turned upset down when I decided to factor MostSigBit function in a single define and suddenly building my project started failing.

Even rewrote this code using if-else statements, no luck still stuck with same results!

```
#define MostSigBit(x)   (x&0x80 == 0x80) (x = x<<1 ^ 0x1B) : (x <<= 1)
#define MultiplyBy2(x)  (x != 0) ? (MostSigBit(x)) : 0
#define MultiplyBy3(x)  (x != 0) ? (MostSigBit(x) ^ x) : 0
```

Comment: Well, how are you using it? We tend to avoid macro's for a reason, we have templates for that. (And, of course, cleverness in user code is almost always a bad thing.)

Comment: Those are not functions, but macros. Macros are *evil*. Consider using [inline functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html) instead.

Comment: `(x&0x80 == 0x80)` you're missing a `?`

Comment: also it'd be good to surround `x` with parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question mark is missing:

```
#define MostSigBit(x)   (x&0x80 == 0x80) (x = x<<1 ^ 0x1B) : (x <<= 1)
```

should be:

```
#define MostSigBit(x)   (x&0x80 == 0x80) ? (x = x<<1 ^ 0x1B) : (x <<= 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Parentheses missing, should be:

```
#define MostSigBit(x)   (((x) & 0x80 == 0x80) ? ((x) = ((x)<<1 ^ 0x1B)) : ((x) <<= 1))
#define MultiplyBy2(x)  (((x) != 0) ? (MostSigBit(x)) : 0)
#define MultiplyBy3(x)  (((x) != 0) ? (MostSigBit(x) ^ (x)) : 0)
```

Consider using inline functions for that, as Frederic wrote macros are evil:

```
inline char MostSigBit(char x) { return (x & 0x80 == 0x80) ? (x<<1 ^ 0x1B) : (x << 1); }
inline char MultiplyBy2(char x) { return x != 0 ? MostSigBit(x) : 0; }
inline char MultiplyBy3(char x) { return x != 0 ? MostSigBit(x) ^ x : 0; }
```